# In bash, replace newline in csv files, except when at line's end

Tags: bash, csv, sed

I have a huge csv file, about 500Mb. The field separator is the pipe char (|). Some lines contain newlines and carriage returns. I need to remove them, but I don't want to remove the legitimate newlines at the end of each lines. I have tried with sed and tr as shown in other questions but I end up removing all newlines, which is not what I want.

Sample input (the ||Yes line should be joined to the previous line):

```
21/06/2016 18:06:32|||||||||||||||||||32 Red|Jrup Vej 6|61069849
||Yes||vals
21/06/2016 18:06:32|||||||||||||||||||101 K|Ser Bevard 110|||No|
```

My attempts:

```
sed -i 's/\r\n//g' myfile.csv

tr -d '\r' < myfile.csv
```

Thanks for any help,
Joe

Comment: You forgot to provide sample input, expected output and your own efforts.

Comment: And how would you know which line-ending was "legitimate" or not? A line-ending is a line-ending is a line-ending. Unless there's some specific context surrounding either the legitimate or illegitimate line-endings, it's impossible to say which line-ending might be legitimate or not.

Comment: Quite tricky. I'd say if a newline is preceeded and followed by some text and a pipe, it is a newline I need to get rid of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A csv data usually has fixed number of columns.

In your case it seems a full record has 25 columns. Based on that you can use this awk command to join broken records:

```
awk -F '|' 'NF < 25 {getline s; $0 = $0 s} 1' file

21/06/2016 18:06:32|||||||||||||||||||32 Red|Jrup Vej 6|61069849||Yes||vals
21/06/2016 18:06:32|||||||||||||||||||101 K|Ser Bevard 110|||No|
```

Answer (score 1):

I love @anubhava's gem of a [command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42094087/1729388).  I amended it for the case where the record is broken by multiple newlines.  Unless I'm missing something, the original would only join two lines maximum and then start with the next line.

```
awk -F '|' '{ while( NF < 25 ) { getline s; $0 = $0 } 1' file
```

Comment: Very nice addition to  @anubhava's reply, thank you!